# App crashes when run on phone

Tags: android, crash, genymotion

My App is crashing when I try to run on phone but it works fine in genymotion.

I can't see any error in genymotion but when I run it on my phone, it keeps on crashing and doesn't show any error

Comment: `it keeps on crashing and doesn't show any error`. you know, i somehow doubt that. There must be something in logcat.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By4q58OsDFIRdXI3eVBmVGVyWFU

here is the link of logcat image

Comment: There must be some reason for crash. Try to spy your `logcat`. And check your app `minSdkVersion` is equal to your mobile's OS version.

Comment: open android monitor (i think it's in tools in Studio) and post logcat from there too

Comment: Check the Android Versions and Compatibility of Your Mobile over Geny Motion

Comment: which type app crashing ? every app or some app ?

Comment: you have given very vague question here, if you are new to android and if you think you code is perfect, see if you have given required permissions in manifest, maybe ur app is trying to access some hardware component which emulators like gennymotion dont have but a physical phone has.

Comment: and your logcat is in verbose, change it to log level : error  to see why app is crashing

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logcat at the time the app crashes. There will be an exception generated. The logcat which you have given has no exception

Comment: App is not crashing when I do test run, when I generate APK file and install in my phone, app crashes in my phone

Comment: Do you have external dependency which requires proguard settings?

Comment: Check in your build.gradle if minifyEnabled is true. If yes then make it false and try and run the app once. If the problem is gone then it us related to proguard. First do this much and then we will see

Comment: Did u test the app on your phone? I mean debug it on your phone itself. Maybe u can find something. It is very difficult to suggest anything without looking at the code

Comment: how to debug in phone ?

Comment: Search it. Many resources are available

Comment: I was using Parse to store data, but had some problem with the 
code I was using in MainActivity file, 

so when I was running it in Genymotion, it was working fine don't know why but when I was trying to run in my phone it was crashing, so when I debugged it directly to phone, it showed me the error, and I fixed it.